# Share to classroom button stopped functioning

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites, google-classroom

I have inserted instances of the Share to Classroom button on my school GSite using GAS.

Html:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
</script>

<? var site = SitesApp.getSite("domain", "webiste name");  ?>
<? var page = SitesApp.getActivePage().getUrl(); ?>
  <div style="height: 35px; ">
  <g:sharetoclassroom size=32 url="<?!= page ?>"></g:sharetoclassroom>
  </div>
```

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('gClassroomShare')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}
```

The web app is published to run as me for anyone in the domain.

They have been working perfectly up until yesterday/today. When I click on the buttons now, the new empty window opens with about:blank in the url.

Any idea what would have happened to break it? Would a setting in the Admin Console block this?

Cheers.

Comment: Are there any errors logged to the JavaScript console when this happens?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what to do about it.  Like I said, it was working fine and now it isn't.

Unsafe JavaScript attempt to initiate navigation for frame with URL 'about:blank' from frame with URL 'https://www.gstatic.com/classroom/sharewidget/widget_stable.html?usegapi=1&…z2c2pcgkwx5go2226ui-script.googleusercontent.com&pfname=&rpctoken=14568689'. The frame attempting navigation is sandboxed, and is therefore disallowed from navigating its ancestors.

Comment: Which browser are you using? If not Chrome, can you try the same thing in Chrome?

Comment: This was Chrome. I just checked Safari and it works fine there.

Comment: I'm not sure why it could have changed, but I think the problem is the way IFRAME sandboxing works. By default all popups created by the sandboxed iframe are also sandboxed themselves. Sandboxing the Classroom popup causes problems, so it isn't loading correctly. I'm not sure if there is any way around this behavior.